# Need to average a row of cells but requiring a minimum of 3 cells to have data

Tags: average, minimum, requirements

I'm trying to build a spreadsheet that tracks trainee progress. The form I've built so far feeds off of daily logs that are set up as other sheets on the same document. The trainer scores tasks 1-5 daily and they feed into the tracker at the last sheet to show progress. I want each task to have to be completed a minimum of 3 times and calculate the average of all the completed tasks after it's been done a minimum of 3 times. A score is calculated based on the average of all tasks in the last cell. I don't want to calculate that average score until 3 cells have data in it and exclude blank cells.

I've googled formulas but can't find one that can require 3 cells to have data.